# How to access the properties of an interface from object inside that interface?

Tags: kotlin, interface

How to access the properties of an interface from object inside that interface?

Example:

```
interface FeatureFlags {
    val version: String
    
    object FF {
        fun instanceBlock(): Boolean {
            return compareVersions(version, "0.19") >= 0 // error, version not found
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
interface FeatureFlags {
    val version: String
    fun instanceBlock(): Boolean {
        return compareVersions(version, "0.19") >= 0
    }
}

interface ApiBase {
    val version: String

    object FF: FeatureFlags {
        override val version: String = this.version // error, this refers to object instead of ApiBase
    }
}
```

The goal is to just have the FeatureFlags interface be namespaced to FF onto another interface.

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
interface LemmyApiBase : PictrsAPI, OldRoutes {
    val version: String
    override var auth: String?

    val FF get() = object: FeatureFlags {
        override val version: String = this@LemmyApiBase.version // need to access LemmyApiBase.version
    }
}
```

now I can access version

Comment: Can you explain what was wrong with the code in the question, and _how_ this fixes it?  This site aims to be a resource where people can improve their understanding.